# Vs 2015 update 1 supports what Typescript versions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

In my office I have VS 2015 update 1. I cant upgrade to VS 2015 update 3 or later.
Company policy wont accept the update.It will take 2-3 months to get the required approvals for update 3 or later.

Please let me know what version of typescript i need to install which is compatible with VS 2015 update 1.

My aim is to develop angular 2 applications

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The download page says you should use RTM or later, so version 2.0.6 should work with update 1.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593